# SSAS cube Deployment

Tags: ssas, ssas-2008

I was trying my hands on building Cubes using AdventureWorksOlap database. I successfully build what I was trying to do. Now my concern is that I want to deploy the cube to a server so that rest of the team members can use this cube as a datasource while generating their SSRS reports (might be some other tools).

I have heard that SSAS does not allows Sql Authentication. So, 
1) how will the members access the cube? 
2) What authentication changes do I need to incorporate? 
3) How can the other developer using his computer's SSMS access the cube and make changes to it (just like we can do it in the OLTP database)? 
4) I need to prepare a dashboard using this cube. Any suggestions on this one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Windows Authentication

2) none.

3) Once the cube is deployed you cant change it. Actually you can change some things like partitions and roles, but you cant add a dimension for example. You need to change the project on BIDS and redeploy it

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks a ton for the prompt reply. I got all your points except the first one. 

The problem is where do I have to set the credentials for the user so that they can access the cube database using SSMS (loggin in Analysis Server) and use that cube as a datasource in SSRS?

Comment: To be more precise:
1) I have prepared a Cube on Machine "Server" and deployed it there only. 
2) I want to access that cube using SSMS so that I can write few  MDX queries. For that I have to login to SSMS in Analysis Server using Windows Auth (as SQl is not allowed). This results in login error.


Does this makes sense?

Comment: makes perfect sense. The SQL login should be disabled by default. I assume your user does not have permissions on server "Server". When you installed the SSAS instance on Server, by default, all windows administrators become SSAS admins. Can you try to log in as a windows admin?

Comment: Got it. You mean that if the windows user is admin that he can easily login in to "Server". But what if he is not?

My my company's environment, they are not windows admin users, though they might have some admin rights. Any way around to this one?

Comment: sure, each SSAS database has "roles" and you can assign your AD user to a role on the cube. You do that on the cube development on BIDS.

Comment: Have you come across any controls or SDK which can be used with Cube for dynamic dashboard? 

I want the almost the similar process (the way we do it in cube).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend starting with Excel Pivot Tables to learn what type of dashboard you will want to create.  By working with the end-users, you can understand what information they want/need to see.

Regarding security, as mentioned, by design cubes use Windows auth only. Here's a [blog](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic546634-17-1.aspx) that talks about circumventing standard security.

Also, I have posted a [series of videos](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1C57B4EE4D873A1D&feature=plcp) on how to create OLAP cubes SSAS in SQL Server 2008 using BIDS.  You may find this series helpful.